# PHP Variable Variables within setter function

Tags: php, oop, variables

I am trying to achieve a way to define an indefinite, but not infinite number of variables, to be used to create objects. I have tried a couple of ways to try this but i cant seem to wrap my head around this.

Here is what i came up with:

```
$aCount= 0;
$Foo = "Bar".$aCount;
$$Foo = array("Data1"=>NULL, "Data2"=>NULL);
function getBarData1() {
     return ${$Foo}['Data1'];
}
function getBarData2() {
    return ${$Foo}['Data2'];
}
function setBarData($newBarData1, $newBarData2) {
    ${$Foo}['Data1'] = $newBarData1;
    ${$Foo}['CONTENT'] = $newBarData2;
    $aCount++;
}
setBarData('First', 'Line');
setBarData('Second', 'Dot');
setBarData('Third', 'Dash');
for($aCount == $aCount; $aCount > -1; $aCount--) {
    echo getBarData1() ."\n";
    echo getBarData2() ."\n";
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would stick to using arrays, they are there to hold variable amounts of data in a structured way rather than rolling your own.  The main problem you are probably having is scope - `$Foo` is in the global scope and therefore not defined in each function unless specifically imported.

Comment: Not sure if that can help, but we can at least pass variable as function names with call_user_func() http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php Also what happen if you use `$$foo` instead of `$($foo)` ? It should work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are heading two problems:

1. [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)
2. value of variable `$Foo` is static and never change - value is always: `Bar0` even when you change `$aCount` because the value is just a string

working example:

```
<?php
$aCount= 0;
$Foo = function(){ global $aCount; return "Bar".$aCount; };
${$Foo()} = array("Data1"=>NULL, "Data2"=>NULL);
function getBarData1() {
    global $Foo, ${$Foo()};
     return ${$Foo()}['Data1'];
}
function getBarData2() {
    global $Foo, ${$Foo()};
    return ${$Foo()}['Data2'];
}
function setBarData($newBarData1, $newBarData2) {
    global $aCount, $Foo, ${$Foo()};
    ${$Foo()}['Data1'] = $newBarData1;
    ${$Foo()}['Data2'] = $newBarData2;
    $aCount++;
}
setBarData('First', 'Line');
setBarData('Second', 'Dot');
setBarData('Third', 'Dash');
$aCountTotal = $aCount;
for($i = 0; $i < $aCountTotal; $i++) {
    $aCount = $i;
    echo getBarData1() ."\n";
    echo getBarData2() ."\n";
}
```

in this case you should use array instead, variable-variable is really usefull in rare cases

array example:

```
<?php
$arr = array();
function getBarData1($index) {
    global $arr;
     return $arr[$index]['Data1'];
}
function getBarData2($index) {
    global $arr;
    return $arr[$index]['Data2'];
}
function setBarData($newBarData1, $newBarData2) {
    global $arr;
    $arr[] = ['Data1' => $newBarData1, 'Data2' => $newBarData2];
}
setBarData('First', 'Line');
setBarData('Second', 'Dot');
setBarData('Third', 'Dash');
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    echo getBarData1($i) ."\n";
    echo getBarData2($i) ."\n";
}
```

better than using global variable in functions is passing data through parameters like:

```
<?php

$arr = array();
function getData1($array, $index) {
     return $array[$index]['Data1'];
}
function getData2($array, $index) {
    return $array[$index]['Data2'];
}
// reference to $array because we want to change the value
function setData(&$array, $newBarData1, $newBarData2) { 
    $array[] = ['Data1' => $newBarData1, 'Data2' => $newBarData2];
}
setData($arr, 'First', 'Line');
setData($arr, 'Second', 'Dot');
setData($arr, 'Third', 'Dash');

for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    echo getData1($arr, $i) ."\n";
    echo getData2($arr, $i) ."\n";
}
```

Comment: Very well explained and thanks alot :) This indeed was what i was looking for. I thought that scope may have been a problem, but couldnt see it straight away thumbs up!!